# Opencart 2.1.0.2 Custom Option disappears on Edit Order

Tags: javascript, php, json, opencart, opencart2.x

I'm using Opencart 2.1.0.2.

I have developed a custom option with type=number and name of quantity that reflects the checkbox code. This is working wonderfully. (It adds correctly from the add order button in the administration and from the front of the store)

However, I have noticed that if I go to edit an order with a product, the option type=number at first appears on the #tab-product page, but then disappears once the cart options load. 
At First: [image]
Then it Disappears: [image]
Note: "Testing2: 30" is a custom option type=text (name is customprice); and it appears fine and registers within the cart system.

**EDIT**
I have figured out that the #button-refresh (which is clicked before entering this tab) is not reloading the product options correctly. I have looked through the database and the type is appearing correctly. Below is the code for when #button-refresh is clicked. Any clues as to why it is not reloading the quantity option?

```
// Add all products to the cart using the api
$('#button-refresh').on('click', function() {
$.ajax({
    url: $('select[name=\'store\'] option:selected').val() + 'index.php?route=api/cart/products&token=' + token,
    dataType: 'json',
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(json) {
        $('.alert-danger, .text-danger').remove();

        // Check for errors
        if (json['error']) {
            if (json['error']['warning']) {
                $('#content > .container-fluid').prepend('<div class="alert alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> ' + json['error']['warning'] + ' <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');
            }

            if (json['error']['stock']) {
                $('#content > .container-fluid').prepend('<div class="alert alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> ' + json['error']['stock'] + '</div>');
            }

            if (json['error']['minimum']) {
                for (i in json['error']['minimum']) {
                    $('#content > .container-fluid').prepend('<div class="alert alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> ' + json['error']['minimum'][i] + ' <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');
                }
            }
        }

        var shipping = false;

        html = '';

        if (json['products'].length) {
            for (i = 0; i < json['products'].length; i++) {
                product = json['products'][i];

                html += '<tr>';
                html += '  <td class="text-left">' + product['name'] + ' ' + (!product['stock'] ? '<span class="text-danger">***</span>' : '') + '<br />';
                html += '  <input type="hidden" name="product[' + i + '][product_id]" value="' + product['product_id'] + '" />';

                if (product['option']) {
                    for (j = 0; j < product['option'].length; j++) {
                        option = product['option'][j];

                        html += '  - <small>' + option['name'] + ': ' + option['value'] + '</small><br />';

                        if (option['type'] == 'select' || option['type'] == 'radio' || option['type'] == 'image') {
                            html += '<input type="hidden" name="product[' + i + '][option][' + option['product_option_id'] + ']" value="' + option['product_option_value_id'] + '" />';
                        }

                        if (option['type'] == 'checkbox') {
                            html += '<input type="hidden" name="product[' + i + '][option][' + option['product_option_id'] + '][]" value="' + option['product_option_value_id'] + '" />';
                        }


        if (option['type'] == 'quantity' || option['type'] == 'text') {
            html += '<input type="hidden" name="product[' + i + '][option][' + option['product_option_id'] + '][' + option['product_option_value_id'] + ']" value="" />';
        }


        if (option['type'] == 'textarea' || option['type'] == 'customprice' || option['type'] == 'file' || option['type'] == 'date' || option['type'] == 'datetime' || option['type'] == 'time') {

                            html += '<input type="hidden" name="product[' + i + '][option][' + option['product_option_id'] + ']" value="' + option['value'] + '" />';
                        }
                    }
                }

                html += '</td>';
                html += '  <td class="text-left">' + product['model'] + '</td>';

        // html += '  <td class="text-right"><div class="input-group btn-block" style="max-width: 200px;"><input type="text" name="product[' + i + '][quantity]" value="' + product['quantity'] + '" class="form-control" /><span class="input-group-btn"><button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_refresh; ?>" data-loading-text="<?php echo $text_loading; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button></span></div></td>';

                html += '  <td class="text-right">' + product['price'] + '</td>';
                html += '  <td class="text-right">' + product['total'] + '</td>';
                html += '  <td class="text-center" style="width: 3px;"><button type="button" value="' + product['cart_id'] + '" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_remove; ?>" data-loading-text="<?php echo $text_loading; ?>" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button></td>';
                html += '</tr>';

                if (product['shipping'] != 0) {
                    shipping = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!shipping) {
            $('select[name=\'shipping_method\'] option').removeAttr('selected');
            $('select[name=\'shipping_method\']').prop('disabled', true);
            $('#button-shipping-method').prop('disabled', true);
        } else {
            $('select[name=\'shipping_method\']').prop('disabled', false);
            $('#button-shipping-method').prop('disabled', false);
        }

        if (json['vouchers'].length) {
            for (i in json['vouchers']) {
                voucher = json['vouchers'][i];

                html += '<tr>';
                html += '  <td class="text-left">' + voucher['description'];
                html += '    <input type="hidden" name="voucher[' + i + '][code]" value="' + voucher['code'] + '" />';
                html += '    <input type="hidden" name="voucher[' + i + '][description]" value="' + voucher['description'] + '" />';
                html += '    <input type="hidden" name="voucher[' + i + '][from_name]" value="' + voucher['from_name'] + '" />';
                html += '    <input type="hidden" name="voucher[' + i + '][from_email]" value="' + voucher['from_email'] + '" />';
                html += '    <input type="hidden" name="voucher[' + i + '][to_name]" value="' + voucher['to_name'] + '" />';
                html += '    <input type="hidden" name="voucher[' + i + '][to_email]" value="' + voucher['to_email'] + '" />';
                html += '    <input type="hidden" name="voucher[' + i + '][voucher_theme_id]" value="' + voucher['voucher_theme_id'] + '" />';
                html += '    <input type="hidden" name="voucher[' + i + '][message]" value="' + voucher['message'] + '" />';
                html += '    <input type="hidden" name="voucher[' + i + '][amount]" value="' + voucher['amount'] + '" />';
                html += '  </td>';
                html += '  <td class="text-left"></td>';
                html += '  <td class="text-right">1</td>';
                html += '  <td class="text-right">' + voucher['amount'] + '</td>';
                html += '  <td class="text-right">' + voucher['amount'] + '</td>';
                html += '  <td class="text-center" style="width: 3px;"><button type="button" value="' + voucher['code'] + '" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_remove; ?>" data-loading-text="<?php echo $text_loading; ?>" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button></td>';
                html += '</tr>';
            }
        }

        if (!json['products'].length && !json['vouchers'].length) {
            html += '<tr>';
            html += '  <td colspan="6" class="text-center"><?php echo $text_no_results; ?></td>';
            html += '</tr>';
        }

        $('#cart').html(html);

        // Totals
        html = '';

        if (json['products'].length) {
            for (i = 0; i < json['products'].length; i++) {
                product = json['products'][i];

                html += '<tr>';
                html += '  <td class="text-left">' + product['name'] + ' ' + (!product['stock'] ? '<span class="text-danger">***</span>' : '') + '<br />';

                if (product['option']) {
                    for (j = 0; j < product['option'].length; j++) {
                        option = product['option'][j];

                        html += '  - <small>' + option['name'] + ': ' + option['value'] + '</small><br />';
                    }
                }

                html += '  </td>';
                html += '  <td class="text-left">' + product['model'] + '</td>';

        // html += '  <td class="text-right">' + product['quantity'] + '</td>';

                html += '  <td class="text-right">' + product['price'] + '</td>';
                html += '  <td class="text-right">' + product['total'] + '</td>';
                html += '</tr>';
            }
        }

        if (json['vouchers'].length) {
            for (i in json['vouchers']) {
                voucher = json['vouchers'][i];

                html += '<tr>';
                html += '  <td class="text-left">' + voucher['description'] + '</td>';
                html += '  <td class="text-left"></td>';
                html += '  <td class="text-right">1</td>';
                html += '  <td class="text-right">' + voucher['amount'] + '</td>';
                html += '  <td class="text-right">' + voucher['amount'] + '</td>';
                html += '</tr>';
            }
        }

        if (json['totals'].length) {
            for (i in json['totals']) {
                total = json['totals'][i];

                html += '<tr>';
                html += '  <td class="text-right" colspan="4">' + total['title'] + ':</td>';
                html += '  <td class="text-right">' + total['text'] + '</td>';
                html += '</tr>';
            }
        }

        if (!json['totals'].length && !json['products'].length && !json['vouchers'].length) {
            html += '<tr>';
            html += '  <td colspan="5" class="text-center"><?php echo $text_no_results; ?></td>';
            html += '</tr>';
        }

        $('#total').html(html);
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Do you need a `<?php if ($option['type'] == 'number') { ?>` to create some HTML for your new option?

Comment: See edit above. The Add Order page, which uses the same tpl file, correctly registers the option even when it automatically adds it (for instance if the cart does not clear). Also, if the html wasn't there, why would it appear then disappear? it's as if the option is being erased.

Comment: If you look at the model file - opencart doesn't update options.... it deletes all of them and then re-inserts them. So if the data isn't passed then they will get erased.